# How to read OSX .plist files from Java?

Tags: java, macos, plist

How to read OSX [.plist files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list) from Java?

Comment: HINT: A `.plist` is an XML file.

Comment: HINT @karim79: No. On Mac it can be in binary form too

Comment: You should probably explain for readers what a .plist file is. It's a Mac file which is, as I understand, an XML-based format in its current incarnation. So, simply use Java's built in XML processing libraries to read it. But perhaps you should also say what you mean by 'read' -- simply get it into memory, parse it, what?

Comment: Actually starting with Mac OS X 10.4 the default format for .plist files is in binary form not in xml form

Comment: [dd-plist](https://github.com/3breadt/dd-plist) enables your Java application to handle property lists of various formats.

Answer (score 15):

Imho running a commandline tool from Java is not quite the "best way to do the job".

There are several much better ways to deal with binary plist in JAVA: That one I prefere is an usefull little project by Daniel Dreibrodt at: [google project hosting](http://code.google.com/p/plist/)

You can also use [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration) (which API is supporting the Property List format). More information about the history of the .plist-format on OSX (which version introduced which format) I wrote up on my [blog](http://blog.elitecoderz.net/read-os-x-binary-plist-with-java/2011/01/)

**Update:** There is a new project hosted at source forge called [Property List Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/plist/files/lib/), that shall be able to read AND write .plist- I have not tested it, but it sounds interesting.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you refer to the plist format used on Mac starting with Mac OS X (and not the NeXTSTEP or GNUstep format).

1. Determine if the file is in XML or binary format
2. If in binary format use the [`plutil`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/plutil.1.html) command-line-utility to convert file to xml format
3. Now you have the file in xml format, use any java-xml-library to handle the plist

Comment: If you're looking for a utility that is available on platforms other than mac, you can look into http://scw.us/iPhone/plutil/. Works fine for me on OS/X and linux, did not try windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library:

[Property List Library (SourceForge)](http://plist.sf.net/)

It will read property list files to objects and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

[Simplified java XML/plist reading.](http://code.google.com/p/xmlwise/)

Comment: xmlwise does NOT support binary plist format, which is actually the standard on OS X ("[Fatal Error] Info.plist:1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog")

Answer (score 0):

These days the Java Preferences API on a Mac automatically uses plist files and they are in binary format. You might be able to read the plist automatically simply by reading the preferences at the "node".

I hope that helps.