# Apple Plist Converted to Java Data Structures

Tags: java, objective-c, plist, xml-parsing

I have a program that is going to be receiving info displayed in it from a .plist on my server. However, I am going to be making this for PC, and I'm using Java to do so. Plist files aren't conventional XML, so common XML parsing libraries don't work. I can't locate any plist specific parsers, so I am lost on how to continue. The way I see it my options are:

a) Locate such a parser for the plist file

b) Make a workaround using a regular XML parser

c) Change the file the program gets its data from (undesirable)

Has anyone else had any experience with plists in languages other than Objective-C?

Comment: AFAIK .plist are regular XML files. At least that is what they claim: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: To an extent, yes. But whereas a normal XML file might look like: "<myPropertyName>myValue</myPropertyName>", plists look like "<key>myPropertyName</key><string>myValue</string>" which makes it a bitch to use regular XML parsers.

Comment: that is perfectly valid XML and you should use an XML parser for that. I guess you would like to use a mapping tool to bind that to a java object, but not many XML binding tools support this. Still, valid, wellformed XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jochen Bedersdorfer notes, `.plist` files are XML with a well-formed [DTD](http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd). Use [`plutil`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OSX/1/plutil/) to convert them from binary to text form.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
```

Addendum: In a comment, you asked

> Isn't it text form when I get it?

Not necessarily. Here's some [history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list) on the subject.

Comment: and here is another question dealing with the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749197/how-to-read-osx-plist-files-from-java

Comment: I suppose I just dont understand XML all that well. Isn't it text form when I get it?

Answer (score 3):

To remove any confusion:

1. A `plist` file can be either in XML or in binary form.
2. The binary plist is of course not XML.
3. The XML plist is of course XML. In fact it's a valid XML... try `xmllint` against an XML plist.
4. Yes it has slightly unconventional structure. As you say, it's like `<dt>title</dt><dd>description</dd>`.
5. You can convert a binary plist to an XML plist using `plutil` on OS X. Convert it to XML before sending it over the network.
6. With a regular XML parser you can get `key` and `string`. Make a hash containing these pairs. Then you get the string based on the key.

Comment: +1 good summary. One other handy tip: If you use `plutil -convert` in place, the `.plist` will be converted back to binary when next accessed.

Answer (score 0):

[dd-plist](https://github.com/3breadt/dd-plist#features) might be helpful.

> Serialize native java data structures to property list objects
>
> Deserialize from property list objects to native java data structures

> You can also directly convert the contained NSObject objects into native Java objects with the NSObject.toJavaObject() method. Using this method you can avoid working with NSObject instances altogether.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.plist</groupId>
  <artifactId>dd-plist</artifactId>
  <version>1.26</version>
</dependency>
```